# Declaring sceneView gives SIGNAL SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, iphone-6

I'm getting a SIGNAL SIGABRT Thread 8 error when I build to my iphone 6, when I build to an emulator there's no problem what so ever, this happened after I updated to the newest version of XCode which was released last february.

The error is:

> Assertion failed: (renderSize.x != 0), function - [SCNRenderContextMetal _setupDescription:forPass:isFinalTechnique:],
>   file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/SceneKit/SceneKit-332.6/sources/Core3DRuntime/NewRenderer/SCNRenderContextMetal.mm,
>   line 688. (lldb)

Why does it work in the emulator but not on an actual device and how can I fix this? Is it that the framework is out-dated?

When I remove everything.. the error only stops once I've removed the following code:

```
var sceneView = SCNView();
```

The iOS version is 9.2.1

Comment: The designated initializer for a sceneView is init(frame:CGRect). What happens when you provide a nonzero frame?

Comment: fixed it, thank you :) @beyowulf that worked :)